# Unix--Send attachment, subject and body of the mail using mailx

Tags: shell-script, mailx

Can you please tell me how to send the attachment, subject and body of the mail using mailx command.

I am using

```
uuencode travel$datestamp.XLS Travel$datestamp.XLS | mail -s "International Savers Tracking" abc@gmail.com -- -f abcd@gmail.com < BodyofTheMail.txt
```

its sending attachment with subject without body of the mail

Answer (score 3):

You're both piping into and indirecting into `mail`; you can only have one standard input.  Also, `uuencode` isn't needed.  Try:

```
mail -s "Subject" -a /path/to/attachments/file.ext mailbox@example.com < /path/to/messagebody.txt
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Thank you.