# Debian mailx won't attach files to emails

Tags: debian, mailx

(Note: I have seen [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359117/unix-send-attachment-subject-and-body-of-the-mail-using-mailx), but it does not work for me)

I am attempting to send an email with an attachment using Bash on Debian Stretch, using the `mailx` package (not mutt). My implementation does not support the `-A` parameter (it's an invalid option), and the `-a` parameter is for adding headers.

I have tried many variations of the following, but they fail for me:

`mail -s "Test" -a /home/user/filename.xlsx user@example.com < /root/emailbody.txt`

The end effect is a plain-text email with the filename as the first line, the header content, then the data inside `/root/emailbody.txt`:

```
/home/user/filename.xlsx
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Hi there
```

I do not have `uuencode`, and many threads are reporting that's the "old" way of sending attachments. I cannot install `mutt` on this server. What are my options?

**Update with uuencode** - I tried running it as the following, but only got "Hi there" as the email result, no attachment:

```
uuencode /home/user/filename.xlsx test.tlsx | mail -s "Test" user@example.com < /root/emailbody.txt
```

Comment: Are you against installing and using [uuencode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102092/117549)?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Tried that, then ran it but it just showed the `/root/emailbody.txt` file in the body, and no attachment. I'll update the question.

Comment: You wrote that you didn't have it, so I wasn't sure if an answer with it would be acceptable ...?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I didn't want extra packages if I could help it, and I saw threads that `uuencode` is the old way. That's the main reason I wanted to avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original command will work if you have the `heirloom-mailx` package installed.

```
sudo apt-get install heirloom-mailx
```

Then you can:

```
mailx -s "Test" -a /home/user/filename.xlsx user@example.com < /root/emailbody.txt
```

Comment: If I replace `mailx` with `heirloom-mailx`, it works!

Comment: FYI for any Ubuntu users who stumble upon this thread.... you should use `s-nail` instead, as `heirloom-mailx` was deprecated in Ubuntu as of 18.04

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/s-nail.1.html

Answer (score 2):

To "attach" a uuencoded file really just means providing that as the body of the email; as a result, you cannot *also* redirect a body in from a file; you'd use:

```
uuencode /home/user/filename.xlsx filename.xlsx | mail -s "Test" user@example.com
```

Comment: So I tried this, but everytime the attachment comes through, Excel reports it's corrupted. New question?

Comment: Possibly; the encoding/decoding should be fine, but any number of things could go wrong along the way.

Comment: Dang... It opens, but has that warning dialog. I'll need to look into it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure!  If you can, for the new question, describe the steps that the email (well, the attachment) takes on its way to Excel. You might consider SuperUser as a more appropriate site, if the issue ends up more on the Windows side.

Comment: I posted the question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1448907/emailed-excel-workbook-appears-broken-after-being-attached)